# PyCharm remote interpreter does not show site-packages content in project tab

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging, interpreter, jetbrains-ide

I've configured PyCharm remote docker-compose interpreter, but I can not see `remote_sources` folder content in Project sidebar, while this folder cached `site-packages` folder of my docker container!

my configs:

[image]
[image]

and `remote_sources` folder that is empty:

[image]

How can I see this folder content in Project sidebar? I want to see django folder structure in my Project sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm in 2019.2 fixed this bug :)

Answer (score 0):

`File` >> `Settings` >> `Project Interpreter`

You can import any library into your project with the plus button next to the Package, version, lastest version

Comment: I'm imported this libraries,(Also in remote docker  interpreter you can not import by plus button), interpreter also using my imported libraries, my problem is showing this imported libraries in `remote_sources` folder on project sidebar